# running a permanent loop as an own process

Tags: multithreading, powershell, winforms

I'm quite new in powershell. I created a form to monitor a few things. One part is pinging servers. The pinging part gets started by a button which starts a function and loops thru an IP lists. The results gets written in a html file. It works fine so far. But if I want to do something else on the form I can't do because the loop is running. Here is the extraction of the function:

```
function StartPings
{
 for ($i=1; $i -le $end; $i++){
    $IP= get-content $IP-list  #file with IP's
    $IP | ForEach-Object{
        $pingResult = test-Connection $_ -count 1 -Quiet
        ... #creates a string with html table row
    }
    ... #creates the full html file
    start-sleep -seconds 60
 }
}
```

How do I have to change the function that it runs in an own process? I'm not sure if it is the right term.

Comment: something like `Start-Job`, or in a new window?

Comment: I'm assuming the linked duplicate offers viable solutions.